# Select N and display N random Rows in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, random, ms-access-2013

I need to select a specific number of random rows from a simple query. The number is specified in a form `([Formulários]![Survey]![SelectSurveySample])`. 
If I try to select TOP 5, it works, but I want to change this number in a form.

```
SELECT TOP ([Formulários]![Survey]![SelectSurveySample]) *
FROM [main_table] mt
WHERE (((mt.CPA_Number)=[Formulários]![Survey]![selectCPA_Survey]) 
AND ((mt.Sample_Household)=False) AND ((mt.Functionality_Survey)=False))
ORDER BY rnd(Int(Now*ID)-Now*Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing the **parenthesis**...

```
SELECT TOP [Formulários]![Survey]![SelectSurveySample] *
FROM main_table
WHERE (((main_table.CPA_Number)=[Formulários]![Survey]![selectCPA_Survey]) 
AND ((main_table.Sample_Household)=False) 
AND ((main_table.Functionality_Survey)=False))
order by rnd(Int(Now*ID)-Now*Id)
```

since this works with changing to `SELECT TOP 5`, and you have a form variable `[Formulários]![Survey]![selectCPA_Survey]` in the query, the only difference I see are the **parenthesis**.

Comment: Yes I tried without the parenthesis and return the same error. Something like this "SELECT statement includes a reserved word or argument that is missing or not inserted correctly or the punctuation is not correct" (my access isn't in english so I translated it).